# Select 2000+ columns as Features for Classification ML

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib

I'm looking how I can select a lot of columns(2000+) as a feature from a Dataframe. I don't want to write the name one by one.
I'm doing classification and i have around 2000 features.

data is a Dataframe with around 2000 columns. 
First, I get all of the columns name of my DF and drop 9 columns because i don't need them.

My idea was to use all the columns names to feed the VectorAssembler. The result should be something like [Value Of the 1st Feature, Value 2nd Feature, Value 3rd Feature...] for the first row and this for all of my Dataframe.

But I have this error :

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field "features" does not exist.

**EDIT :** If something is unclear, please let me know that I can fix it.

I deleted some Transformers because it's not the point of my question.(StringIndexer, VectorIndexer, IndexToString)

```
val array = data.columns drop(9)

val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
  .setInputCols(array)
  .setOutputCol("features")    

val Array(trainingData, testData) = data.randomSplit(Array(0.8, 0.2))

val rf = new RandomForestClassifier()
  .setLabelCol("indexedLabel")
  .setFeaturesCol("features")
  .setNumTrees(50)


val pipeline = new Pipeline()
  .setStages(Array(assembler, rf))

val model = pipeline.fit(trainingData)
```

**EDIT 2** I fix my problem. I took off the Vector Indexer and used array in the VectorAssembler and it worked perfectly.
Well at least, I get a result.

Comment: for which line do you get the error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field "features" does not exist`

Comment: It was on the pipeline.fit(trainingData) 
I fixed it. You can see EDIT 2. :)